# What is this : document.reservation.submit(); supposed to do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am reworking on a code of an old developer and I'm trying to do a form for reservation.

I've looked across the whole code the only thing called reservation is the name and the id of the form.

Form who's is in style : `display:none` ...

So two question in one :  First of all what the heck is supposed to do

`document.reservation.submit();` Is it suppose to get the form by his name ?

Shouldn't it be something like  `document.getElementById('reservation').submit()` instead ?

And my second question is : How the form can be sent if all the value are set to `display:none` I tough it couldn't work and if you want to hide them you shall use hidden property...

I need a bit of help on this guys pls :)

### Form for beter comprehension :

```
<form name='reservation' action='http://xxxx/reservationFormAction.to' method="POST" id="reservation">
    <input type="hidden" id="productLive" name="product" value="{$product.info.code}"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="complementaryParameters" value=""/>    
    <input type="text" name="depCityCode" id="depCityCode" style="display:none"  />
    <input type="text" name="dateDep" id="dateDep" style="display:none" />
    <input type="text" name="nightDuration" id="nightDuration"  style="display:none" />
    <input type="text" name="dayDuration" id="dayDuration"  style="display:none" />
    <input type="text" name="provider" value="{$product.tourOperator.code}" style="display:none" />
    <input type="text" id="toProduct" name="toCode" value="{$product.info.toProductCode}" style="display:none" />
    <input type="text" name="catalogCode" value="{$product.info.code}" style="display:none" />
    {if $ecall}
    <input type="text" name="reservationProfileChannelCode" value="ECALL" style="display:none" />
    {else}
    <input type="text" name="reservationProfileChannelCode" value="ADV" style="display:none" />
    {/if}
    <input type="text" name="nbAdults" id="nbAdults" style="display:none" />
    <input type="text" name="nbChildren" id="nbChildren" style="display:none" />
    <input type="text" name="nbBabies" id="nbBabies" style="display:none" />
    <input type="text" name="productUrl" id="productUrl" style="display:none" value="http://www.xxxx.com/{$product.slug}_{$product.info.code}.html" />
    <input type="text" name="homeUrl" id="homeUrl" style="display:none" value="http://www.xxxx.com" />
    <span id="ageChild" style="display:none"></span>
<div class="update-search clearfix">
```

Comment: the display none or hidden info will always be sent even that you can't see.... Usually we pass some info that the user doesn't need to know, like USER_ID=20 .....---- and the document.reservation.submit, ------- it submits the form with name="reservation"

Comment: does the code dont produce any output ?

Comment: Forms are available as properties of the `document` object by name.

Comment: Ask **one** question per question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`document.reservation` gets the `HTMLFormElement` for the form with the `name` `reservation`. Then calling `submit` submits the form (without triggering the `submit` event).

So why not `document.getElementById`? That would *also* work, but `document.reservation` works because the `document` object gets various properties created on it automagically, including properties referring to forms by their `name`. This is covered in [§3.1.3 of the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#dom-tree-accessors) *(you have to scroll down a fair bit):

> The `Document` interface supports named properties. The supported property names at any moment consist of the values of the `name` content attributes of all the `applet`, exposed `embed`, `form`, `iframe`, `img`, and exposed `object` elements in the `Document` that have non-empty `name` content attributes, and the values of the `id` content attributes of all the `applet` and exposed `object` elements in the `Document` that have non-empty `id` content attributes, and the values of the `id` content attributes of all the `img` elements in the `Document` that have both non-empty `name` content attributes and non-empty `id` content attributes.

The value of those properties is the element the `name` or `id` came from.

The `window` object also gets properties for every element with an `id`, as [described here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object):

> The supported property names at any moment consist of the following, in tree order, ignoring later duplicates:
>
> - the browsing context name of any child browsing context of the active document whose name is not the empty string,
> - the value of the `name` content attribute for all `a`, `applet`, `area`, `embed`, `form`, `frameset`, `img`, and `object` elements in the active document that have a non-empty `name` content attribute, and
> - the value of the `id` content attribute of any HTML element in the active document with a non-empty `id` content attribute.

Where again the value of those properties is the element the `name` or `id` came from.

In both cases, this is the HTML5 specification standardizing the previously-widespread-but-nonstandard practice most browsers had, which is widely used on pages in the wild.

---

> How the form can be sent if all the value are set to display:none I tough it couldn't work and if you want to hide them you shall use hidden property...

It's best to ask **one** question per question.

The CSS `display` property has no effect at all on whether form fields are submitted; you're probably thinking of the field's [`disabled` state](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fe-disabled): Disabled form fields are indeed left out of the form on submission.

Comment: @NexusDuck: Intended. :-)

Answer (score 1):

the display none or hidden info will always be sent even that you can't see.... Usually we pass some info that the user doesn't need to know, like USER_ID=20 .....---- and the

```
document.reservation.submit
```

------- it submits the form with name="reservation"